# Why does Vue 3's `setup(props) { props.id }` return undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

Why does `setup(props) { props.id }` return `undefined` from `watchEffect(() => fetch(getUrl())` callback, (Vue 3 `watchEffect` function)?

example using function `useFetch(() => url)`

i.e,
`const { data, error, isPending } = useFetch(() => https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${props.id})`

results to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/undefined`

expected: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 // id++ { 2, 3, ... }`

See the code snippet below;

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script>
  const { createApp, ref, watchEffect } = Vue; 

  useFetch(getUrl => {  
    const data = ref(null)          
    const error = ref(null)           
    const isPending = ref(true)

    watchEffect(() => fetch(getUrl())
      isPending.value = true
      data.value = null
      error.value = null

    return { data, error, isPending }
  })

  const Post = {
    template: `...`,
    setup(props) {
      console.log("setup props.id: ", props.id)  // returns undefined
      
      const { data, error, isPending } = useFetch(() => `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${props.id}`) // jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/undefined
    }
  }
  
  const App = {
    components: { Post },
    data() {
      return {
        id: 1
      }
    },
    template: `
    <button @click="id++">change ID</button>
    <Post :id="id"/>
    `   
  }

  createApp(App).mount("#app");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With composition API (`setup(props)`) you still need to define what the component props are.

Here is what that might look like.

```js
const Post = {
  template: `...`,
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log("setup props.id: ", props.id) // now works
    // etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans @Daniel . Just adding on the "Why" part, the docs states that;

"
When setup is executed, the component instance has not been created yet. As a result, you will only be able to access the following properties:

    props (probably Proxy only),
    attrs,
    slots,
    emit.

In other words, you will not have access to the following component options:

    data,
    computed &
    methods,
"